# Can I access office 365 shared folder via IMAP?

Tags: node.js, imap

I am using [imap](https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap) module from npm and I have no idea to connect to the office365 shared mailbox.

It is my configuration:

```
const Imap = require('imap');
const imap = new Imap({ 

host: 'outlook.office365.com',
user: 'myEmailAccount\sharedMailbox',
password: 'myEmailPassword',
port: 993,
keepalive: {
    interval: 3600,
    idleInterval: 3600,
    forceNoop: true
},
tls: true,
});
```

if it is not allowed to connect the shared mailbox via imap, is there any other method to connect it?

Comment: A folder is a [directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_(computing)). It is not the same as a mailbox.

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6369118f-7dee-4728-ac1c-a0c706b3d290/office-365-exchange-online-how-to-access-a-shared-mailbox-using-thunderbird-or-other-imap-client?forum=onlineservicesexchange mention that I can access the shared folder if I add the sharedMailbox name after the user account but It doesn't work

Comment: Notice that the backslash \ has a special meaning in JavaScript literal strings.

Comment: seen it can't access via IMAP. is there any method to access the shared folder via nodejs program?

Comment: "It doesn't work", "it is not allowed". You don't describe what you're trying and neither what the error is, only your goal and your interpretations of the error messages resulting form your undescribed attempts. I'm going to vote to close.

Comment: use a forward slash instead of backslash